# Problem displaying replies as part of author's latest comments on author page

Tags: templates, author, array, comments

I've based a lot of my method on this thread [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/59039/display-number-of-comment-replies)

I can currently display 5 latest comments on an author template page. I want to display the latest 3 replies from any user for each 'main' comment (hence parent=0)

I can recognise the replies through print_r but using for example get_comment_link for the comment_id is a complete no show and recognises no replies.

Here's the code.

```
    <?php $args = array(
        'user_id' => $curauth->ID,
                    'number' => 5,
                    'status' => 'approve',
                    'parent' => 0
                    );
$comments = get_comments($args);
   if ( $comments )
    {
foreach($comments as $c){
    echo '<ul id="authorcomments">';
    echo '<li>';
    echo '<a id="authorcommentlink" href="'.get_comment_link( $c->comment_ID ).'"> ';
    echo get_the_title($c->comment_post_ID);
    echo '</a>';
    echo "</br> <div id='authorcommentexcerpt'>" .  get_comment_excerpt( $c->comment_ID );
    echo "</div></li>\n";
    echo '</ul>';

    $parent_comment_id = $c->comment_ID;
    $comment_meta_args = array(
                               'status' => 'approve',
                               'parent' => intval($parent_comment_id),
                               'number' => 3
                               );
    $replies = get_comments($comment_meta_args);
    echo '<ul id="authorcomments">';
    echo '<li>';
    echo '<a id="authorcommentlink" href="'.get_comment_link( $replies->comment_ID ).'"> ';
    echo get_the_title($replies->comment_post_ID);
    echo '</a>';
    echo "</br> <div id='authorcommentexcerpt'>" .  get_comment_excerpt( $replies->comment_ID );
    echo "</div></li>\n";
    echo '</ul>';
}

} else { echo "<p style='text-align: center'> Nothing! </p>\n";} ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

My bad. Should have added a foreach for the replies as well.

```
 <?php $args = array(
        'user_id' => $curauth->ID,
                  'number' => 5,
                'status' => 'approve',
                'parent' => 0
                );
 $comments = get_comments($args);
    if ( $comments )
 {
foreach($comments as $c){
echo '<ul id="authorcomments">';
echo '<li>';
echo '<a id="authorcommentlink" href="'.get_comment_link( $c->comment_ID ).'"> ';
echo get_the_title($c->comment_post_ID);
echo '</a>';
echo "</br> <div id='authorcommentexcerpt'>" .  get_comment_excerpt( $c->comment_ID );
echo "</div></li>\n";
echo '</ul>';


$parent_comment_id = $c->comment_ID;
$comment_meta_args = array(
                           'status' => 'approve',
                           'parent' => intval($parent_comment_id),
                           'number' => 3
                           );
$replies = get_comments($comment_meta_args);
foreach($replies as $r) {
echo '<ul id="authorcomments2">';
echo '<li>';
echo '<a id="authorcommentlink2" href="'.get_comment_link( $r->comment_ID ).'"> ';
echo get_the_title($r->comment_post_ID);
echo '</a>';
echo "</br> <div id='authorcommentexcerpt2'>" .  get_comment_excerpt( $r->comment_ID );
echo "</div></li>\n";
echo '</ul>';
}

}




 } else { echo "<p style='text-align: center'> Nothing! </p>\n";} ?>
```